# Update the Korean Galaxy S

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s, updates

I use a Korean version of Galaxy S (SHW - M110s) phone which runs on android 2.3.6., I want to update it to ICS or JB.

I have rooted the phone with major sufferings and flashed with Nakyup ROM. XDA dev people strongly advised me not to update the phone and that may cause a phone brick. But yet I have seen some videos of people in youtube has installed ICS on SHW M110s and they are reluctant to reply my queries.

I understand the hardware architecture may difference for mine and the international Galaxy S. If anybody is there to help me in order to update my phone ? Anyone done it before ?

Answer (score 1):

ICS or Jelly Bean cannot work on this particular phone due to hardware limitations, and many ROMS like [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/) etc. are designed for the international version, not the korean version, thus you will have some problems.

My recommendation to you is to use [KIES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Kies) to go back to the latest Samsung released Gingerbread, root, then use a custom kernel ([Tegrak](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tegrak.lagfix) is my personal choice) to get a lagfix. It will hopefully breathe new life into your phone. Hope this helps.

Also note there're many apps for Gingerbread that give you the feel and performance of ICS, such as [Gallery ICS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moblynx.galleryics), [Camera ICS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moblynx.cameraics), and [ICS Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.SyndicateApps.ICSv2). Aside from being unable to run Chrome, you may not notice any difference.